How to generate N transition functional coverage bins for N-bit coverpoint?
If I have a N bit coverpoint, and I want to generate N bins, each bin corresponding to 1 bit of my coverpoint such that each bin covers 0->1 transition for each bit of the signal, how do I proceed?
I know I can say bins[] = {8'b00000000 => 8'b11111111} and another way is to define coverpoint for 1 bit and instantiate it 8 times for a 8 bit coverpoint signal, but that's not what I want. It is a functional coverage and a separate bin is required for covering each line of the signal, that it is asserted. It can be addressed with toggle coverage(yes) but I need to do a functional coverage here.
I have intrpt defined as logic [63:0] intrpt deep in the design.
And then a snippet of my coverage class looks like below
covergroup xyz;
    option.per_instance = 1;
    option.get_inst_coverage = 1;

    coverpoint top.abc.intrpt {
        bins asserted[] = {0=>1};
    }

The idea here is to have a coverage for each input interrupt line like

bin[0] hit corresponds to intrpt[0] was asserted
bin[1] hit corresponds to intrpt[1] was asserted
......
bin[63] hit corresponds to intrpt[63] was asserted


You need to explain why you cannot use toggle coverage as a requirement for functional coverage. and why you can't use an array of groups, one element for each for functional coverage.

"why you can't use an array of groups, one element for each for functional coverage" - I can use that. Functional coverage is needed to analyze if the interrupts have been forced. Is there some other alternative ? Can you please help me with a small example if I want to use array of groups.

There are many ways of collecting functional coverage; a covergroup in SystemVerilog is just one of several constructs. A executable testplan will let you link a requirement to a

covergroup
cover directive
toggle coverage
assertion statement
code coverage
test execution
etc...

You'll need to check your tools documentation on how to create the linkage.
If you are intent on using an array of covergroups, you can connect each bit of a vector to a covergroup element.
covergroup xyz(int index) @(posedge clk);
    option.per_instance = 1;
    coverpoint top.aintrpt[index] {
        bins asserted = {0=>1};
    }
endgroup
xyz cg[N];
initial foreach(cg[i]) cg[i] = new(i);

